# How to build a proof for $\vdash \exists y \forall x P(x,y) \rightarrow \forall x \exists y P(x,y)$ using the software Fitch

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, natural-deduction

I want to build a proof for $\vdash \exists y \forall P(x,y) \rightarrow \forall x \exists y P(x,y)$ using the software Fitch...

[image]

I have the above proof and I want to test it to be sure I have done that right, however I cannot prove anything in such software as I cannot even get started since I do not have any premises for the sequent...

## Edit

[image]

That's everything I have so far... Could some of you help me validate if the proof tree is true and help me build such a proof in the Fitch?

## Edit 2

[image]

Comment: You need to do a subproof, where you assume $\exists y \forall x \ P(x,y)$, and try to end the subproof with $\forall x \exists y \ P(x,y)$. To do a subproof in Fitch, go to Proof->New Subproof, or hit CTRL-P

Comment: Hey, @Bram28, what can I do next, because I cannot yet do the elimination of the existential?... I have edited my question

Comment: Take a look at exercise 13.18 from the book!

Comment: A link to that application?

Comment: The premise of course will be $∃y∀x P(x,y)$ and the conclusion will be $∀x∃y P(x,y)$. The final step will be $(\to \text I)$.

Comment: Intermediate steps are obvious: you have to remove the quantifiers: $(\exists \text E)$ and $(\forall \text E)$ and then re-introduce them: $(\exists \text I)$ and $(\forall \text I)$.

Comment: Ok, @MauroALLEGRANZA, I have done as you said... But I cannot still get that done... Please take a look at my edit 2

Comment: @lucasbbs  It is because you are trying to apply the inference too early.  It takes place at the end of the subproof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}$
In Fitch systems, the existential elimination rule references an existential statement, and a subproof, whose assumption is a witness for that statement, that concludes with a statement that *does not contain* the witness variable.$$\boxed{~~a.~~\exists x~\phi\\\fitch{~~b.~~\boxed\alpha ~\phi[x\backslash\alpha]}{~~~~\vdots\\~~c.~~\psi}\\~~d.~~\psi\qquad\exists \mathsf E~a,b{-}c}$$

Thus you are looking to build
$$\fitch{}{\fitch{~~1.~~\exists y~\forall x~P(x,y)}{\fitch{~~2.~~\boxed a~\forall x~P(x,a)}{\quad\vdots\\~~\mathrm m.~~\forall x~\exists y~P(x,y)}\\~~\mathrm n.~~\forall x~\exists y~P(x,y)\hspace{18ex}\exists\mathsf E~1,2{-}\mathrm m}\\~~\mathrm o.~~\exists y~\forall x~P(x,y)\to\forall x~\exists y~P(x,y)\qquad{\to}\mathrm I~1{-}\mathrm n}$$

Note: Line 2 is an *assumption*, with fresh variable $a$.